# Dijit NumberSpinner Wrap

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have two Dijit NumberSpinners which I am using to select hours and minutes, however, when I reach the min and max constraints it just stops spinning, is there a way to get it to wrap around and start at zero if someone is at the maximum and clicks the up arrow, and the same at the down arrow?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dojo.connect("spinner", "onchange", foo);` and a couple of if statements inside foo and `dijit.byId("spinner").attr("value", 0);` etc.